# Why does `cv2.threshold` only takes grayscale image?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on some projects related to OpenCV and came across `cv2.threshold` function. Why does this function only take grayscale images only? Can anybody make this clear to me?

Comment: Presumably because nobody has found it useful to implement it for color images.

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57): "The function applies fixed-level thresholding to a multiple-channel array." Browsing through the older versions of the documentation, it seems this has been the case since OpenCV 3.3 (released in August 2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE:

See comments on this question instead of reading it.

---

---

I agree with @Cris as he said in the comments "nobody has found it useful to implement it for color images".

There are plenty of functions to achieve the same in much concise way which depend on your use-case.

But it's still a general curiousity question from a newcomer. So one easy approach for the same would be:

```py
def bgr_threshold(src_bgr, thresh_bgr, maxval_bgr, type_bgr):
    b, g, r = cv2.split(src_bgr)
    thresh_b, thresh_g, thresh_r = thresh_bgr
    maxval_b, maxval_g, maxval_r = maxval_bgr
    type_b, type_g, type_r = type_bgr

    ret_b, thresh_img_b = cv2.threshold(b, thresh_b, maxval_b, type_b)
    ret_g, thresh_img_g = cv2.threshold(g, thresh_g, maxval_g, type_g)
    ret_r, thresh_img_r = cv2.threshold(r, thresh_r, maxval_r, type_r)

    thresh_img_bgr = cv2.merge((thresh_img_b, thresh_img_g, thresh_img_r))

    return ((ret_b, ret_g, ret_r), thresh_img_bgr)

ret, th = bgr_threshold(image, (127, )*3, (255, )*3, (cv2.THRESH_BINARY, )*3)
```

Although this makes it take almost 3 times slower from optimisation point of view.

Comment: I would just use a more recent release of OpenCV, as it's already supported for over 2 years now. :)

Comment: @DanMašek, oops, well didn't knew, maybe being updated with version changes is a good idea.